# Using .tsv data in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use .tsv demographic data in D3 to create interactive population pyramids, and while I have enough knowledge about D3 to create them, I don't know how to load the data. I have been using only JSON data while learning how to use D3 (with the help of Mike Dewar's awesome book), but I didn't use TSV or CSV data until now.

Can you help me so I can get started with this project? I know I have to use d3.tsv("file", function) but some things still bug me. For example, if I want to create divs or SVG rectangles for every bit of data in a column, how do I tell the program to get the "i" from the data?

This is an example of the data:

```
AGE A08    M08    F08    A09    M09    F09
0   40.8   20.9   19.9   40.9   20.9   19.9
1   40.7   20.8   19.9   40.8   20.9   19.9
2   40.6   20.8   19.8   40.7   20.9   19.9
3   40.5   20.7   19.7   40.6   20.8   19.8
```

Is this even .tsv? As far as I understand, tsv means tab separated values, while these are separated with a space. If this is not a .tsv file, how can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `d3.tsv()` is your friend if you're parsing a *true* TSV. By true, I mean that it's just like a CSV, but with tabs instead of commas. The formatted table you included as example might sometimes have two consecutive tabs, just to achieve the proper columns spacing, and that would not constitute a TSV. I'm guessing your TSV file is just fine.

Regarding your question about getting `i` for each value: well, often, CSV/TSV data is presented in a 2-dimensional table form, in which case you don't just deal with `i` but also `j`. I.e. tables are structured in terms of rows and columns, not just a flat list of values. In d3, there's a pattern for working with stuff like this. For example, check out [this example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) or [this tutorial](http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/) (scroll down to the section called **Binding two-dimensional data**).

If you're looking to create an SVG rectangle for each value, you'd probably still want to follow the 2-dimensional table pattern, rather than flattening the data. In this case, you'd create an SVG group for each row and nest within each group the rectangles corresponding to each row's values.

Of course there are other ways to represent this data, for example, as stacked bar chart. In this case, check out [`d3.layout.stack`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout). In this case too, you wouldn't need to flatten your data.

If you truly come up with a case in which you need to flatten the data into a single array of values, you would do so in plain javascript, using a loop that gathers the values in whatever fashion you need. But I doubt you'll need to go down this route.